Why does Django Rest Framework Pagination work with Django.http JsonResonse() and not rest_framework.response Response()
I've followed the tutorial on enabling/creating custom pagination for ModelViewSets in Django Rest Framework (DRF).
But the custom pagination doesn't show up as part of the content of the response. I only get my results split according to the 'PAGE_SIZE' setting in an object labeled data with no count, or page_size as defined in my custom pagination class.
I added the following lines in my setting.py file:
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'core.pagination.CustomPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 2,
    ...
}

Custom pagination class:
from rest_framework import pagination
from rest_framework.response import Response

class CustomPagination(pagination.PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 2
    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return JsonResponse({
            'page_size': self.page_size,
            'count': self.page.paginator.count,
            'results': data
        })

My ModelViewSet
class PersonViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    """
    A simple ViewSet for listing or retrieving and creating people.
    """
    queryset = Person.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer
    pagination_class = CustomPagination

I have tried changing the ModelViewSet to various other types such as genericViewSet and defining my list() functions etc.
The results from the list API endpoint I expected:
{
  "page_size": 2,
  "count": 2548,
  "results": [
    {
       "type": "Person"
    },
    {
       "type": "Person"
    }
  ]
}

The results from the list API endpoint I got:
{
  "data": [
      {
        "type": "Person"
      }
      },
      {
        "type": "Person"
      }
    }
  ]
}

When I tried changing the response type in my CustomPagination class to JsonResponse I got the result I expected. Why is this?
Changed CustomPagination Class:
from rest_framework import pagination
from django.http import JsonResponse

class CustomPagination(pagination.PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 2
    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return JsonResponse({
            # 'page': self.page.paginator.page,
            'page_size': self.page_size,
            'count': self.page.paginator.count,
            'results': data
        })


If you comment out the override for get_paginated_response(), what do your results look like?
